# Understanding constraint in scipy's optimize

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to understand `constraints` in the `scipy` optimize function. I want to minimize the function under the assumption, that input values would always be positive. So I have my constraint function defined as follows:

```
def apply_constraint(inputs):
    return inputs[0] - inputs[0]
```

What would happen if all my inputs are negative? I tried with negative inputs but could not understand the result. What is the constraint attribute really meant for? It also gives results with negative values.

Here is my complete code.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def f(x):
    Y = ((x + 100) / 100)
    return Y[0]


def apply_constraint(inputs):
    return inputs[0] - inputs[0]


my_constraints = ({'type': 'eq', "fun": apply_constraint})

min_result = minimize(f, [2], method="SLSQP", options={
                    'disp': False}, bounds=[(-2, 101)], constraints=my_constraints)

print("Minima found at: X = {}, Y = {}".format(min_result.x, min_result.fun))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint function is incorrect

`inputs[0] - inputs[0]` will always be 0, it should be

```
def apply_constraint(inputs):
    return inputs[0]
```

Constraints work in one of two ways either `type = 'eq'` or `type = 'ineq'`

The constraint function will be evaluated and compared with `0`

For an equality constraint the constraint function will be forced to `= 0`

For an inequality constraint the constraint function will be forced to be non-negative i.e. `>=0`

In this case using the constraint function above and `type = 'ineq'` should work

Comment: The OP wants to know how does the constraint_function impact the results. You could try explaining this with an example.